# Switch between Multiple Customised Lang & Region settings on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, language, automator, regional-settings, system-preferences

I need to be able to switch quickly between two or three customised Language & Region prefs on Mac OS X. While there is an advanced tab which allows customisation, there is no way to save this as a preset, so at the moment, switching means laboriously redoing an advanced setup each time.

Is there a way to save each advanced setup as some kind of .plist file that I could switch out (while logged in on my user account) using an Automator action / script or something like that?

Background: I need to do this because I run accounts for businesses in multiple countries and unfortunately, Quickbooks for Mac 2014 insists on pulling currency, number formats and date formats from the current system prefs. Setting up two sep. users isn't really a workable option either for space / time / file access reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AppleScript switching between USA and France:

```
property theSettings : {"", ""}

set settings1 to {"Americas", "United States"}
set settings2 to {"Europe", "France"}

if theSettings is settings1 then
     set theSettings to settings2
else
     set theSettings to settings1
end if

set {theRegion, theCountry} to theSettings

tell application "System Preferences"
     activate
     set current pane to paneid "com.apple.Localization"
     tell application "System Events"
           tell window "Language & Region" of process "System Preferences"
                 tell pop up button "Region:" of group 1
                       delay 0.25
                       click
                       delay 0.25
                       clickmenu itemtheRegion of menu 1
                       delay 0.25
                       clickmenu itemtheCountry of menu 1 of menu itemtheRegion of menu 1
                 end tell
           end tell
     end tell
     quit
end tell
```

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6881161

Comment: Thanks for updating this thread, @polkus - some more good info on that apple discussion thread for other countries as well.